# Matrix equation $\mathrm A \mathrm B \mathrm C^T \mathrm D \mathrm B \mathrm A^T \mathrm C = \mathrm A \mathrm B^T$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Hi I have this question shown the image below. I have made two attempts at it
[image]

I want to if any of my attempts are correct. If so, which one?
There is an error at line 2 of attempt 2 but my answer is how I intended. Ignore the error. I made the error because I was taking my method down from another page which had it written correctly.

Comment: I made a mistake with the second line of the second attempt but my answer still turned out like intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ways are correct with the only exception that in the second try, you forget the $A$ matrix that is premultiplying the $B^T$ matrix, so it would be:

$D=(ABC^T)^{-1}AB^T(BA^TC)^{-1}=C^{-T}B^{-1}A^{-1}AB^T(BA^TC)^{-1}=(BC^T)^{-1}B^T(BA^TC)^{-1}$.

It can be seen that the answer is equal to the first try. The only property I am using to get the equivalent answers is that for A,B invertible matrices: $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Comment: I thought order was important in matrix multiplication...AB not neccessarily equal to BA. That is why I was asking about the two attempts.

Comment: The order matters, and the inverse reverses the order. Think of it like this: if $v$ is a vector, then $ABv$ means apply $B$ to $v$, then apply $A$ to the result. In order to reverse this combined action, you have to first undo $A$ (since that is what you did most recently), then undo $B$. Thus the switching of the order.

Comment: @rert588 Order is indeed important, Josu is making no assumptions like $AB=BA$. If you are wondering about $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, this is **not** saying something like what you suggest; generally, $A^{-1}B^{-1} \neq B^{-1}A^{-1}$. Instead, it's just the statement "If you do B first and then A, to undo it you undo A first, and then undo B". (Whoops, sorry Nick for duplicating your comment!)

Comment: Order is always important in matrix multiplication, observe that $(AB)^{-1 }=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $(BA)^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$, so they must not be the same. So in the question the switching comes for the property, not because of commutativity in matrices

Comment: Looks like we all posted similar comments within the same minute!

Comment: Thanks a million guys. Your help is really appreciated.